# Frameworks for SMS interface

Tags: frameworks, sms

We would like to build an SMS-based application where a customer would send an SMS to a special number like 56060 followed by some keywords. The application will parse the keywords and respond with details related to the keyword.

Are there frameworks to do this?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Twilio http://www.twilio.com/

They are very developer friendly and have some great documentation. They use a very simple XML messaging structure for communicating between your code and their SMS services.